# jQuery change TD color

Tags: jquery, colors

I'm trying to change the color of a TD cell when I click on it. First I needs to check data on page.php though:

```
$(".change").click(function(event) {
    var section = $(this).data('id');
    $.post("page.php", { td: change }, function(data){
        $(this).css('background', '#000'); <------- THIS
        });
    });
```

How can I make the `this` line work? I understand I need to set `this` to something, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope (context) of this is changed in the function callback.

Something like this should work:

```
$(".change").click(function(event) {
    var self = this;
    var section = $(this).data('id');
    $.post("page.php", { td: change }, function(data){
        $(self).css('background', '#000'); <------- THIS
    });
});
```